# 'init_by_lua_block' directive not getting executed on nginx start

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, openresty

I wanted one of my lua script to get executed whenever nginx server starts or is reloaded. I tried using init_by_lua_block and init_by_lua_file directive but i dont see any log traces for the lua script in init_by_lua_block when i run the nginx docker. My http block looks like below. nginx.config is located in container path/etc/nginx/nginx.conf .

```
http {
    sendfile on;
    init_by_lua_block /etc/nginx/lua/init.lua;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy-config.conf;
 }
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> init_by_lua_block
>
> syntax: init_by_lua_block { **lua-script** }

https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#init_by_lua_block

`init_by_lua_block` expects inlined Lua code, not a path to the Lua file.

Use `dofile` to execute Lua script:

```
init_by_lua_block {
  dofile('/etc/nginx/lua/init.lua')
}
```

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-dofile

or use `init_by_lua_file`:

```
init_by_lua_file /etc/nginx/lua/init.lua;
```

**UPD:**

You should use the `NOTICE` logging level (or higher) in `init_by_lua_*` directives because your `error_log` configuration is not yet applied in this phase:

> Under the hood, the init_by_lua runs in the nginx configuration loading phase, so your error_log configuration in nginx.conf does not take effect until the whole configuration is loaded successfully (due to the bootstrapping requirements: the configuration loading MAY fail). And nginx initially uses a logger with the NOTICE filtering level upon startup which is effect in the whole first configuration loading process (but not subsequent configuration (re)loading triggered by the HUP signal).

https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/issues/467#issuecomment-82647228

So, use `ngx.log(ngx.NOTICE, ...)` (or `ngx.WARN`, `ngx.ERR`, etc. — see https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#nginx-log-level-constants) to see the output in the log.

Alternatively you can use `print`. It's equivalent to `ngx.log(ngx.NOTICE, ...)` under the hood: https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#print

Comment: I've updated the answer. Probably this is the problem with the logging level you use (sorry, I overlooked the “dont see any **log traces**“ part of your question).